# How can I place image in top left aligned with <appbar> using react js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I tried this but it is placed in top left (on top of the web page)

```
<img className={classes.image} src={logo} position={'left'}/>
```

The whole app.js html

```
 return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <div>
        <img className={classes.image} src={logo} position={'left'}/>

      </div>
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar}  position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Courses</Typography>
        <img className={classes.image} src={formation} alt="icon" height="60" />
      </AppBar>
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
              <Posts setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Form currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I would appreciate the help - thank you.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Be more specific